# What's the best way to clean dust from film negatives?

Tags: film, 35mm, dust, negative-scanner

Every time I scan my 35mm negatives, there is always a lot of dust, even after using a rocket duster and wiping with a microfiber cloth. What sort of equipment exists in order to get rid of the dust? I’m using a dedicated 35mm scanner that has IR dust removal, but that too isn’t that great. I try deleting every dust particle manually in Photoshop, but as you might imagine, it takes hours and is far from completely effective, especially with larger particles. Do you think it would be better just to make prints with an enlarger and then scan those?

Answer (score 1):

Although I never personally needed to do this, I found pretty fast on the internet guides on how to do it

- [How to scan film](http://howtoscan.ca/scanning-tips/clean-negatives-before-scan-alcohol.html)
- [Kodak guide](http://www.kodak.com/global/en/consumer/products/techInfo/cis145/cis145.shtml)
- [Video guide on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Z3CpALUO9o)

Bottomline what those guides are saying is:

- first thing you want to try is a cloth (those special cloths used for photographic works)
- you HAVE to use gloves while handling the film.
- some guides are recommending NOT to use compressed air on the film, because that would actually push more dust and debris on the film.
- last resort is using a Isopropyl Alcohol based solution to clean the film.
- you have to pay special attention to the side of the film holding the emulsion, as that's exactly what holds the information (the image) on the film. Handle with care not to add new scratches.